# Title for the player that's trying to get others talking in " silence game"

Tags: vocabulary, slang, dictionaries

I play the "silence game" with my kids, in which you win if you remain silent the longest, while a player is trying to get others talking. As we take turn playing; what term best describes the role of such player?

Comment: I suggest the same method kids already use when playing ["Tag, Touch-and-Go"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_(game)) - *You're "**it**!"*  Apparently, *In India, the player who is "it" is referred to as the "**denner**"*. But that wouldn't be understood by mainstream Anglophones, whereas "it" almost certainly would, even in a relatively unfamiliar context..

Comment: LOL, it's not just me then!!

Answer (score 4):

This is perhaps a dialect/regional thing, but I'll share it because it's a bit silly, as such games usually are. Also, I don't know if it would apply to this particular game, or if other English speakers around the world would use this, or perhaps I'm just showing my age . . .

Here in some parts of the UK, for games like hide and seek, or tig (aka tag), where you have one person who controls the flow of the game, and then it's time for somebody else to take their turn in this role, we would say "You're **it**".

It's my turn, I'll be **it**!

No, it's his turn, he can be **it**

No! Can I be **it**?

Comment: Nothing in the relevant Wikipedia page implies this usage is any more or less common on either side of the pond.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - interesting, that might suggest it's quite an old tradition. I wonder how far back it goes.

Comment: If only children knew how to keep records of their culture...

Comment: You know, now that i think of it, i guess "it" would fit the description. Cheers mate.

Comment: It's usually behind a paywall (subscription-only), but you can often access the full OED with a UK library card number. It's their definition C-1-a. *In children's games: (the name of) the player who has the task of catching or touching any of the others. Also figurative and in extended use.* For which their first citation is 1825: *J. Jamieson Etymol. Dict. Sc. Lang. Suppl.   It, a term applied, in the games of young people, to the person whose lot it is to afford the sport. Thus, in **Blindman's Buff**, he who is blindfolded is **It**,* I forgot that game!

Comment: ...Kipling, 1923: *As the sides are chosen and all submit \ To the chance of the lot that shall make them ‘It’.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - yeah I saw that.  Nice. I hope it hasn't died out. I knew it as blindman's bluff . . . a variation perhaps?

Comment: *LOL, it's not just **me** then!!* I only *thought* about that when copying in that last comment, but you've prompted me to ferret out [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Blind+mans+Buff%2CBlindmans+Buff%2CBlind+mans+Bluff%2CBlindmans+Bluff&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=30&case_insensitive=true), showing that it *used* to always be ***Buff*** - but during *our* lifetimes, ***Bluff*** has surged ahead to take the top slot! (We have our fingers firmly on the linguistic pulse! :)